# Difference when setting as framework"'image-classification" and framework="mxnet' in AWS Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, mxnet

I am using AWS Sagemaker to perform image classification. My understanding is that Sagemaker would use MXNet for image classification by default.(based on the answer [Sagemaker multi-model endpoints with unsupported built-in algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819978/sagemaker-multi-model-endpoints-with-unsupported-built-in-algorithms))

Would someone clarify what difference there is between the following two cases?

Case 1

```
algorithm_image=image_uris.retrieve(
    region=boto3.Session().region_name,
    framework="image-classification"
)
```

Case 2

```
algorithm_image=image_uris.retrieve(
    region=boto3.Session().region_name,
    framework="mxnet"
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`image-classification` refers to the SageMaker Algorithm. As such the Algorithm container will be used where you just need to send your data as input:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/image-classification.html

`mxnet` refers to the MXNet Framework container where you have full flexibility to define your training script:
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/mxnet/using_mxnet.html

Comment: isn't the Algorithm container the same as the the MXNet Framework container.  The answer posted on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819978/sagemaker-multi-model-endpoints-with-unsupported-built-in-algorithms by Swil says that image classification uses Apache MXNet. I suppose Swil is right. 

Thanks.